# Insert table values from a SQL database to an ArrayList

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to insert some values from my database into an ArrayList. I guess there is some problem with the method showMeeting(). Hopefully you guys can understand some of the message get from the console.

```
public ArrayList<String> showMeeting() {

    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String meetID = "SELECT meetID FROM Meeting";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(meetID);
            while(rs.next()){
                output.add(rs.toString());
            }
        } catch (SQLException s) {
            System.out.println("Wrong sql-query");
        }
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InteractWithDatabase2 test = new InteractWithDatabase2();
    ArrayList<String> meetID = test.showMeeting();
    String meetings = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <meetID.size(); i++) {
        meetings += meetID.get(i) + "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(meetings);

}
```

When I'm trying to run this in Eclipse, i get this message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)       at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method)       at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
>     at
>   no.ntnu.fp.model.InteractWithDatabase2.visMoter(InteractWithDatabase2.java:107)
>     at
>   no.ntnu.fp.model.InteractWithDatabase2.main(InteractWithDatabase2.java:127)

Comment: Incidental comment but this line: `output.add(rs.toString());` is going to add a value that's something like "ResultSet@0x000FF". You probably want `output.add(rs.getString("meetID"))`, which will append the value of the meetID column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your mysqlXXX.jar file into the proper directory .. then it will work..

Answer (score 2):

Nothing seems to be wrong with your code, you are just missing the mysql connector .jar on your classpath.

You can download it from [the download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) or via Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Okey, just downloaded it from the download page. I'm quite new to this, but when you say classpath I quess you mean my package in Eclipse where I have the class? And is it just to copy the .jar-file from the folder I just downloaded into my classpath?

Comment: If you use Eclipse, you'll usually add it as a User Library. Copy it somewhere where you'll find it, e.g. `C:\dev\libs`. Right-click your project: `"Build Path" > "Add Libraries" > "User Library" > "User Libraries" > "New ..." (Enter a name, e.g 'mysql') > "add Jars ..." ( select the jar you downloaded ) > "OK"`